# GWT: creating a text widget for highly customized data entry

Tags: gwt, textbox, textarea

I'm trying to implement a kind of "guided typing" widget for data entry, in which the user's text entry is highly controlled and filtered. When the user types a particular character I need to intercept and filter it before displaying it in the widget. Imagine if
you will, a Unix shell embedded as a webapp; that's the kind of thing I'm trying to implement. I've tried two approaches.

In the first, I extend a `TextArea`, and add a `KeyPressHandler` to filter the characters. This works, but the browser-provided spelling correction is totally inappropriate, and I don't see how to turn it off. I've tried:

> DOM.setElementProperty(textArea.getElement(),
>   "spellcheck", "false");

But that seems to have no effect- I still get the red underlines over
"typos".

In the second approach I use a `FocusWidget` to get KeyPress events, and a separate `Label` or `HTML` widget to present the filtered characters back to the user. This avoids the spelling correction issue, but since the `FocusWidget` is not a `TextArea`, the browser tends to intercept certain typed characters for internal use; e.g. FireFox will use the "/" character to begin a "Quick Find" on the page, and hitting Backspace will load the previous web page.

Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might just be able to use `event.preventDefault()` on your keypress events to avoid these browser behaviors. Otherwise, maybe a hybrid of the two approaches? Have a hidden `TextArea` with focus, accepting key events, and then post the typed characters to a separate `Label`.

Comment: This did the trick- a FocusWidget with event listeners that call event.preventDefault().

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific GWT method on TextBox for this, but this simple line of 
GWT code fixes the problem for Chrome (for other browsers, YMMV - it may depend upon how completely they implement HTML5) by setting an attribute on the underlying input element:

```
myTextBox.getElement().setAttribute("spellCheck", "false");
```

Perhaps this attribute is a relatively new feature.